# Execute PHP callback after timeout on server

Tags: php, callback, timeout

I'm designing a PHP login system and I would like to allow users to reset their password if they've forgotten it. The idea is to send a (hashed) custom reset code via email. When user clicks on link, the code is compared with the corresponding stored in database.

To enforce security, I would like to clear code stored in database after 1 day from the request. On forgotten request, I would launch a timeout which runs on server (even if user closes browser) and after 1 day invokes a callback which clears database code. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need to delete it from the database in order to invalidate the code?  Just store the timestamp of when the code was requested, then when the user tries to reset their password, test to see if the difference between now and then is less than one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you log the timestamp when the user sent the password reset request and then on the password reset page, you compare the timestamp in the database with the current timestamp?

You don't need to set a time-out or cronjob this way.

Comment: Tricky! Simple and efficient. Thanks very much.